# 'Remove-LocalUseraccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I need to delete 20+ local accounts on some remote clients. I'm trying to use the single command below:

```
Remove-LocaluserAccount -ComputerName server1.domain.com -Username username
```

However, I'm getting error

> 'Remove-LocalUseraccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to import a module?

Comment: What version of Powershell are you using (what does $psversiontable report?) and what version of Windows are you running on? Both of these are important, as even if the version of Powershell theoretically supports the command, the underlying OS data may not.

Comment: uhm, "Remove-LocaluserAccount" is not a default cmdlet is it? It might be useful to show how you include the code that provides the function

Answer (score 0):

`Remove-LocalUser` was added in Windows 1607. If this is the not the version of Operating System you are using, you will not have the cmdlet to execute the command.

Some alternative methods you can use are `Delete` method on the `Win32_UserProfile` class. Or you can use `net user`